# Azure cosmos db error in data factory - data flow sink -> job failed due to reason: Conversion from StructType

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I'm building a simple `data flow` in azure data factory to get some specific data from a content hub location. This information is in json format.

Transformations:

1. Source: `rest API` get method to retrieve the data from the URL
2. Transformation 1: `flatten` to put into rows an item list that  contains all the articles.
3. Transformation 2: `select` to chose specific attributes from each items in the list.
4. Transformation 3: `alter row` to `upsert` data if condition `true()`
5. Sink: using cosmosdb dataset to load the selected data into a collection.

[image]

The problem is with the last item `elements` since this is a `StructType` `{}`:

```json
elements: {
  headline: {
    title: "Title",
    dataType: "string",
    name: "headline",
    variations: { },
    multiValue: false,
    :type: "string",
  },
  alternativeHeadline: {
    title: "Subtitle",
    dataType: "string",
    name: "alternativeHeadline",
    variations: { },
    multiValue: false,
    :type: "string",
  },
  author: {
    title: "Author",
    dataType: "string",
    name: "author",
    variations: { },
    multiValue: false,
    :type: "string",
  },
...
}
```

When I run the job I'm getting this error:

```
{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: Conversion from StructType(StructField(headline,StructType(StructField(:type,StringType,true), StructField(dataType,StringType,true), StructField(multiValue,BooleanType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(title,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true), StructField(variations,StructType(StructField(mobile,StructType(StructField(:type,StringType,true), StructField(dataType,StringType,true), StructField(multiValue,BooleanType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(title,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true)),true), StructField(spanish,StructType(StructField(:type,StringType,true), StructField(dataType,StringType,true), StructField(multiValue,BooleanType,true), StructField(name,StringType,true), StructField(title,StringType,true), StructField(value,StringType,true)),true)),true)),true), StructField(icon,StructType(StructField(:type,StringType,true), StructField(dataType,StringType,true), StructField(multiValue,BooleanType,true),","Details":""}
```

It seems one ore more data struct types are wrong from the source vs the target but I would like this to be dynamic. Since it is some metadata, the attribute can or can't be there.

I tried using a `copy activity` directly in a pipeline using the same dataset and it worked fine the problem is I'll need to transform the data later and the copy activity is limited in this aspect. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the root of the problem. In the dataset, I imported the schema, once I cleared it, the struct data type verification stopped in the data-flow. The load ran successfully.

[image]

[image]